# Specify Nuget dependencies when building from Azure Devops

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget, azure-pipelines

I've got a build pipeline that pushes a project to Nuget. However, the settings for the pack task configuration is currently $(BuildConfiguration).

As it currently stands, I have to add all the other Nuget package that my package uses manually to the end Project. Is there any way to specify dependencies in the pipeline task? If not, can I combine the variables from the pipeline with a .nuspec file? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a nuspec file to pack from the nuget pack task. And you can check "**Include referennced projects**" if your package referenced to other projects.

[image]

> You can also use nuget custom task to run your custom commands.

[image]

Hope above helps!

Comment: Thanks! Took a Little bit of fiddling to get the custom command to find the correct csproj, and to have the push command pick up the result, but it wasn't too difficult once you pointed me in the right direction. Mostly to do with staging vs source directories.